# system.formatexception input string was not in a correct format when selecting a value in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Everytime I pick any value from the meatyqty dropdownlist even in the other dropdownlist, the error "input string was not in correct format. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(x.ToString(),x.ToString());
        tidalqty.Items.Add(item);
        meatyqty.Items.Add(item);
        darknessqty.Items.Add(item);
        macaroniqty.Items.Add(item);
        cheesyqty.Items.Add(item);
        baconqty.Items.Add(item);
        loveqty.Items.Add(item);
    }        
}

protected void tidalqty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tidalprice.Text = ((double.Parse(tidalqty.SelectedValue)) * 250).ToString();
    computetotal();
}

protected void meatyqty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    meatyprice.Text = ((double.Parse(meatyqty.SelectedValue)) * 500).ToString("f2");
    computetotal();
} 

void computetotal()
{
    double sub1 = double.Parse(tidalprice.Text);
    double sub2 = double.Parse(meatyprice.Text);

    subprice.Text = (sub1+sub3).ToString("f2");              
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this exception?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this?  You really need to see what the value of the string you are parsing is when the exception occurs to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely running into trouble as you are adding to / rebuilding the list on each post back, so it's having trouble with `SelectedValue`.

Try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      int x;
      for (x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
      {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(x.ToString(),x.ToString());
        tidalqty.Items.Add(item);
        meatyqty.Items.Add(item);
        darknessqty.Items.Add(item);
        macaroniqty.Items.Add(item);
        cheesyqty.Items.Add(item);
        baconqty.Items.Add(item);
        loveqty.Items.Add(item);
      }       
    } 
}
```

I've basically added a call to [`Page.IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Additionally, (as someone pointed out in a comment that's now been deleted) there's a typo in the `subprice.Text = (sub1+sub3).ToString("f2");  ` line and it should be `sub2`.